# SearchHits is not giving exact number of documents

Tags: java, elasticsearch

While I am searching in elastic search it gives SearchHits more than no of documents. I want to implement ES in spring boot using java-rest high level client. How can I get no of documents as I want to print them. As in my case no of doc is 10 and search hit is 14. So, in for loop it gives ArrayIndxOutOfBound. How to handle that

```
SearchHits searchHits = searchResponse.getHits();
SearchHit[] searchHit = searchHits.getHits();
for(int i=0; i < searchHits.getTotalHits() ;i++)
{
     ...
}
```

Comment: getHits() returns the hits belonging to the current page. On the other hand getTotalHits() retrieves all hits.

Comment: @AlejandroGonzález what is the diff between SearchHits and SearchHit?

Comment: in your example "searchHits" is just a container object that includes the total number of matches and the array with the hits of the current page (per default I think is 10 elements). "searchHit" is just the array with the hits of the current page.

Comment: Great. 1 more problem. If I will use to return all match like QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery() which is supposed to give all data(assume 12), but it will give 10 as per you(I also marked in ES not in java). How to handle that?

Comment: The idea would be to modify the size parameter of the query (by default 10). Take a look here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html

Comment: Yeah.. I forgot it totally. Thanks Alejandro you are a life saver

Answer (score 0):

As SearchHit calulate hits and inner hits so it will be more or equal to hit documents

Instead of using termination condition as getTotalHits() use getHits()

```
SearchHits searchHits = searchResponse.getHits();
SearchHit[] searchHit = searchHits.getHits();
for(int i=0; i < searchHits.getHits().length ;i++)
{
     ...
}
```

Here, searchHits.getHits() returns a array of SearchHit. Then using length on that array we can know no of hits